Should I include a BOM with my encoding?
In TeXnicCenter I have the option to save files as utf-8 with or without BOM.  Which one should I choose?

Check out this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-with-bom

Since the April 2018 release LaTeX supports BOM, so it shouldn't matter. I prefer without.

without BOM is better.

For any reader like me wondering what BOM means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
